# Debian 12 - Games crash on startup when using Lutris and Steam Proton

Tags: debian, crash, steam, games

I have recently installed Debian Stable 12 in an attempt to revive my 2009 Dell Vostro A860 - a laptop with a Pentium DC T2390 CPU, Intel GMA X3100 integrated graphics and 2Gb of RAM. To maximize performance I am using i3wm with no extra DE installed.

I have then installed flatpak Steam and flatpak Lutris, as to have the most recent libraries available, and was met with issues when running games under proton and wine, which gave me the following errors:

Lutris:

```
2023-07-24 11:26:57,291: ['glxinfo', '-B'] command failed: Command '['glxinfo', '-B']' timed out after 5 seconds
2023-07-24 11:26:57,462: No available glxinfo output
2023-07-24 11:26:57,463: Invalid glxinfo received
2023-07-24 11:32:30,409: Starting Lutris 0.5.13
2023-07-24 11:32:31,448: glxinfo is not available on your system, unable to detect driver version
2023-07-24 11:32:31,449: GPU: 8086:2A02 1028:029A (i915 drivers)
2023-07-24 11:39:58,233: Runtime disabled by system configuration
2023-07-24 11:39:59,205: Unable to load libGLX_nvidia.so.0
2023-07-24 11:39:59,206: Unable to locate libGLX_nvidia
2023-07-24 11:39:59,353: Runtime disabled by system configuration
2023-07-24 11:39:59,389: Runtime disabled by system configuration
Started initial process 42 from gamemoderun /home/kostya/.var/app/net.lutris.Lutris/data/lutris/runners/wine/lutris-fshack-7.2-x86_64/bin/wine /home/kostya/Games/battlefield-1942/drive_c/Program Files/EA Games/Battlefield 1942/BF1942.exe
Start monitoring process.
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
fsync: up and running.
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
2023-07-24 11:40:21,026: ['glxinfo', '-B'] command failed: Command '['glxinfo', '-B']' timed out after 5 seconds
2023-07-24 11:40:21,026: No available glxinfo output
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  0 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  338
  Current serial number in output stream:  338
```

Steam:

```
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=240 -- /home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Source/hl2.exe' -steam -game cstrike\0
Game process added : AppID 240 "/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=240 -- /home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Source/hl2.exe' -steam -game cstrike", ProcID 699, IP 0.0.0.0:0
chdir "/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Source"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
GameAction [AppID 240, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 975 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 1267 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 975 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 1267 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 975 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
WARNING: discarding _NET_WM_PID 1267 as invalid for X11 window - use specialized XCB_X11_TO_PID function!
Proton: Upgrading prefix from None to 8.0-104 (/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/compatdata/240/)
fsync: up and running.
wine: RLIMIT_NICE is <= 20, unable to use setpriority safely
ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 899
                                             ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 892
                                                                                          ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 702
                                                                                                                                       CGlibContextManager: g_main_context_iteration() exceeded budget, deferring outstanding requests to the next frame
                        ThreadGetProcessExitCode: no such process 904
                                                                     Game process updated : AppID 240 "/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=240 -- /home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Proton - Experimental'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/home/kostya/.var/app/com.valvesoftware.Steam/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Source/hl2.exe' -steam -game cstrike", ProcID 896, IP 0.0.0.0:0
                                                                                       Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 240
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198143773553 [API loaded no]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dxvk::DxvkError'
```

Nevertheless, native games, such as CS 1.6, installed through Steam run perfectly fine. I have so far tried installing wine through APT, installing new mesa drivers (both 32 and 64 bit), executing "export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=..." in the terminal, installing lutris specific wine versions through ProtonUp, installing nvidia drivers (to fix the libGLX_nvidia.so.0 error) and obviously a lot of rebooting.

Here is my glxinfo output:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_get_drawable_type, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_ATI_pixel_format_float, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) 965GM (CL) (0x2a02)
    Version: 22.3.6
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 384MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: compat (0x2)
    Max core profile version: 0.0
    Max compat profile version: 2.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 2.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) 965GM (CL)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 22.3.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
...
```

I have researched solutions on the internet, and have not managed to find any that correspond with my specific set of issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for taking the time to read through my post.

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive research, it has turned out that the reason applications would fail to run under proton/wine was due to DXVK.

This is because both DXVK and VKD3D translate DirectX calls into Vulkan, which is unfortunately unsupported on the Vostro A860's particular iGPU - the GM965/GL960, according to this Intel article:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html

In an effort to solve this issue, I have tried running Proton games with `PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1 %command%` launch parameter, which converts DirectX calls to OpenGL instead, but as it stands, most games simply do not support this feature, and therefore I was unable to run "Counter-Strike: Source" in neither Proton, nor native without crashes or visual glitches, rendering gaming on this 15 year-old marvel impossible.